# How to differentiate between "to do" and "do" terminologically?

Tags: terminology

I would like to know what is term for a verb when is with "**to**" (for example "We need "to do" it.) and a verb that is without "to" (for example: "We **do** it everyday"). Now I read [the article infinitive on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive) but it is not clear to me how differentiate between them.

Answer (score 1):

They are often referred to as "infinitive with 'to'" and "infinitive" (or "bare infinitive").

I prefer to call "do" the "base form" (infinitive is one of its uses).

**Edit**: Correction: the form in your second example is not the "bare infinitive"/"base form", but the (not third-person-singular) present form. For nearly all verbs this is the same as the base form.

Comment: The second example the question asker gives is *We do it every day* (heh), and here we're not talking about the plain form of *do*, but the **plain present** form, whereas in the first example (*We need to do it*) we have the **plain form** of *DO*. Only *BE* exhibits the distinction in shape between these two forms, however. You can keep your terminology provided you make this exception explicit. (+1 regardless.)

Comment: You're right: I am guilty of not reading the question carefully. I assumed the second example was of bare infinitive, and it's not. I will edit.

Comment: I often write *to*-infinitive, myself.

Answer (score 0):

- **I do** the work every day. do = is the verb, the main verb in the sentence, aka an action verb.
- I need **to do** the work today. a to-infinitive with the verb to need [something].

  Verbs with to-infinitives
  **We use the to-infinitive after certain verbs (verbs followed by to-infinitive), particularly verbs of thinking and feeling:** [there is an entire list here.]

Need, like want, love, hate, is considered a verb of feeling: I need to leave now.

[to-infinitive from the British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/infinitives)

[The examples would be the same in American English.]

Answer (score 0):

Verbs that aren't infinitives are [*finite*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_verb).

Comment: Actually, no.  There are other non-finite forms as well.